# Clustering method for 2-D data that self-detects number of clusters and takes care of outliers

Tags: clustering, k-means, outlier

Assuming I have data that looks something like that:
[image]
I'm looking for a method or algorithm that can perform the clustering (e.g. as shown in the picture), that automatically determines the optimal number of clusters while also accounting for outliers.
Would appreciate suggestions of methods or relevant implementations/libraries/pipelines, preferably in Python.

Answer (score 3):

DBSCAN is the algorithm of choice for this task.

This a density based algorithm which will look for clusters according to two main parameters, `epsilon` and `min samples`.

It will also identify those samples that do not form any cluster according to prior parameters as outliers.

From Scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan):

> The DBSCAN algorithm views clusters as areas of high density separated by areas of low density. The central component to the DBSCAN is the concept of core samples, which are samples that are in areas of high density. A cluster is therefore a set of core samples, each close to each other (measured by some distance measure) and a set of non-core samples that are close to a core sample (but are not themselves core samples). There are two parameters to the algorithm, `min_samples` and eps, which define formally what we mean when we say dense. Higher `min_samples` or lower `eps` indicate higher density necessary to form a cluster.

[image]

Additional material worth to be checked:

https://www.naftaliharris.com/blog/visualizing-dbscan-clustering/